# Text Generation

Tags: neural-network, javascript

I want to generate „human like“ text/posts based on a dataset of posts from a forum. The dataset contains roughly 25k words.

I currently have the Markoc chain implemented, but i want to improve the text generated by using reccurent neural networks. My problem is that most of the solutions available are written in python, but i need to implement it in either JavaScript or PHP. 
Does anyone know how to do that or where to find a food solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text generation can be done in JavaScript with RNN/LSTM. For example, TensorFlow.js is a JavaScript implementation of TensorFlow. Since the dataset is very small (25k words), model can be run in JS as well.

Following is an example of text generation in JS : https://github.com/reiinakano/tfjs-lstm-text-generation